# problems installing numpy on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: macos, numpy, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install Numpy on an OSX 10.6.8 using Homebrew, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ eb$ brew install numpy --with-openblasWarning: Xcode not installed
Most stuff needs Xcode to build: http://developer.apple.com/xcode/
==> Installing numpy dependency: tbb
==> Downloading http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/77/189/4.1%20update%2
######################################################################## 100,0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 072333068fa278635582846eaaa22d51c0100e09
Actual: 08140939b4a84052734dc3589c59af7560c01990
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tbb-4.1u1.tgz
(To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

I've removed the file named above several times using the following command:
rm -rf/Library/Caches/Homebrew/tbb-4.1u1.tgz

But the same message keeps appearing. Can someone point me to the best way of fixing this? Thank you!

Comment: As the error messages says, it looks like you haven't installed Xcode yet ?

Comment: That's only the warning though, right? I think the error is the SHA1 mismatch, which I'm trying to fix by removing the tbb-4.1u1.tgz file

Comment: OK - I just tried it here but there doesn't seem to be a formula for numpy by default, so I guess you're using a custom formula ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by custom formula, sorry. But these are the directions that I'm following: http://penandpants.com/2013/04/04/install-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: OK - the page you link to confirms what I thought: *I use a Homebrew recipe so I avoid some problems with SciPy. The recipe isn’t included in stock Homebrew though, it requires “tapping” two other sources of Homebrew formula* - I guess there may be a problem with those third party formulae ?

Comment: ok. Do you know of another way to install Numpy? It's taking me forever and I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: FWIW I just followed the instructions on the page you linked to and everything worked fine for me - the only difference is I'm using OS X 10.8 and I have Xcode installed. Try running `brew update` and `brew doctor` ?

Comment: Correction - I got past the threadingbuildingblocks stage successfully but then some time later I got a failure due to a FORTRAN link error.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I got a bunch of warnings when i ran brew doctor. Is there a way that I could share them with you? I'm not sure how to interpret them. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just heading out to dinner, but I suggest posting the errors as a question on http://apple.stackexchange.com where there are plenty of people who are knowledgeable about Homebrew etc. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommends using Macports and spyder. The install went off no problem and then there is a nice environment with numpy, scipy and matplotlib all working for OsX

Comment: Macports was causing me one of the worst experiences I had while installing the scientific Python stack on Mac. It takes hours and seems to install an armada of unnecessary dependencies - even Perl was being installed! Homebrew is slick, fast and definitely the way to go.

Comment: That's your opinion... I had no trouble with it.